# Transparent use of registers though hiding of get/set wrapper

Tags: c, caching, macros, embedded, reusability

I'm working in a embedded project where the functionality of a existing software is realized with a new software-architecture on a new hardware.

The goal is to control a complex hardware unit.
The old software had the registers of the unit mapped into memory and the software is directly modifiying those registers.

Like this:

```
/* Register is defined with offset */
#define REGISTER_1 regMem[0x1234]

/* And can be accessed like this (obvious) */

REGISTER_1 = 0;
if (REGISTER_1 == 0) {...}
```

On the new hardware a wrapper (which cannot be ommited) only allows access to those registers in a

```
SET(REG_ADDR,VALUE);
GET(REG_ADDR);
```

manner.

Do i have any change to reuse the old, big codebase controlling the registers WITHOUT rewriting every register access?

Is there a way to hide GET/SET functions within a macro?

```
#define REGISTER_1 ??? /* Return value with 
GET(REGISTER_1) if not accessed with an assignment like REGISTER_1 = ... */
```

I thought about a cache like mechanism in macro code which sets a dirty flag on a local copy of the register and automatically updates / fetches the register on access...

Comment: It looks like you’ll need to identify how the registers are used and make appropriate changes.  The changes are that the patterns of use are highly stylized and a carefully crafted Perl script (or other similar powerful scripting language of choice) can do the job 95+%, leaving a few cases to be mapped manually.

Comment: This isn't "WITHOUT", but this is the correct way to do such a refactoring since wrapped register access is more future proof than hacks. (I've done this before, it's worth it). Create the GET and SET functions for the registers on the old hardware. Change the registers accesses to use the functions on the old hardware, one by one, testing often just to make sure that things keep working. Your goal is to delete or at least rename all the old "REGISTER_1" and such variables. Once you achieve that, the only thing left will be to use the GET/SET functions from the new hardware.

Comment: If you could use c++ in the new project, you could do this. But foregoing that, @Art's idea is probably the best approach. You may even be able to do a binary compare on the output to make sure everything matches. One way to identify issues would be to change all accesses to GETs and let the compiler issue errors when it was expecting lvalues.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you are trying it the wrong way around. Accessing hardware registers is quite far from the C mental model of storing a value in a variable. While the standard mentions side-effects of operations in the respective paragraphs and provides `volatile` for cells changing contents outside the control of the compiler, chances are that the C programmer coming after you will have a different or no view alltogether on the deeper ramifications of the standard wording applied to your special case. Therefore a lot of information is lost/hidden when we are tricking the human reader into reading some seemingly harmless assignments. Worse yet if you are using interruptible tasks, where the nemesis of read-modify-write errors may come upon you (e.g. `DigiPort_A |= 1;`).

Given that the register accesses will hopefully be uniform in your old codebase, I would try the approach recommended by Jonathan Leffler and let the extra work be an apprentice's due for the customer, signaling him that embedded programming shouldn't be seen as just an Electrical Engineer's side occupation.